# Python2/Windows7: Opening filename that contains a german Umlaut

Tags: python, file, encoding, tkinter

I'm trying to open a file whose filename has been created by typing it in a `ttk.Entry` to which a `Tkinter.StringVar` is attached.

If I'm trying to `open()` the file again by typing the same filename into another 
Entry this fails if I use german 'Umlaute'.

I get a `utf-8` encoded string from the `.get()`-Method of the `StringVar`.

When I list the files in the current working directory, they are not `utf-8` encoded. (I'm using Windows 7!)

How to deal with that?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Unicode handling is quite different between Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7. And declared `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: A sidenote re *When I list the files in the current working directory, they are not utf-8 encoded.* --> Note that the fact that your terminal might not show them correctly does not mean Python won't process them right. Can you post your actual code?

Comment: What does `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` return on your system? That's probably the encoding you should use for your `open` call. You could also just pass a `unicode` string and let the `open` function do the encoding for you.

Comment: `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` returns `mbcs`. How can I configure which coding is used for `open()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import sys
import os
from pprint import pprint
import pickle


class TestApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.varFilename = tk.StringVar()
        self.etyFilename = ttk.Entry(master=self, textvariable=self.varFilename)

        self.frmBtn = ttk.Frame(master=self)
        self.btnSave = ttk.Button(master=self.frmBtn, text='Save',
                                  command=self.save)
        self.btnOpen = ttk.Button(master=self.frmBtn, text='Open',
                                  command=self.openFile)

        self.etyFilename.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.EW, padx=3, pady=3)
        self.frmBtn.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
        self.btnSave.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.SE, padx=3, pady=3)
        self.btnOpen.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.SE, padx=3, pady=3)

        self.mainloop()

    def save(self, *args):
        someData = {'foo': 'bar'}

        filename = self.varFilename.get()

        try:
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump(someData, f)

        except IOError, e:
            print e
            sys.exit(1)


    def openFile(self, *args):
        filename = self.varFilename.get()
        print filename

        print 'Files in cwd:'
        pprint(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))

        try:
            with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                someData = pickle.load(f)
                print someData

        except IOError, e:
            print e
            sys.exit(1)


TestApp()
```

Comment: This is an example because the actually module is too big.. As I see now THIS WORKS even if I use an umlaut. So the error has to be somewhere else. I have to go through the routine that creates the filename. Perhaps there is another kind of error which I'm not thinking about right now. Sorry.